# Receiving null data issue at backend

Tags: asp.net-core

Base64: null issue

}

This is the data that i'm sending from my frontend
[image: data]

And this is my model in backend

```
 public class xyz
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string xyz { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> Base64 { get; set; }

        
    }
```

I think the problem is related with the base64 data in my model so how do i fix this issue

}

Comment: can `public Dictionary<string, string> Base64 { get; set; }`   ---> `public object Base64 { get; set; }` help you to receive data?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your model, then this is how I send my request:

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {
            var a = {};
            var b = {
                0:"asdfasdf"
            };
            a.base64 = b;
            a.hubxCategoryId = "11";
            a.patientId = 3210;
            a.notes = "good";
            a.isTestApprove = false;
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7175/Home/postModel",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify(a),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Then in my controller I can receive the data. See screenshot below.

```
[HttpPost]
public string postModel([FromBody] HubxTestApprovedForPatientModel model)
{
     return "hello";
}
```

[image]

If I don't have the `[FromBody]` in my controller, the model will be null.

[image]

Comment: what i need to change in my model. I have [FromBody] in my controller. The only data which i'm receiving null is base64 data

Comment: I used the same model as yours, and I've showed you how I send the request, then it can work for me. Now could you pls show your code about send the request and set the request parameters?

Comment: so `this.hubxTestApprovedForPatient[0].base64= this.fileList;` base64 is a list? Then you should use `public list<object> Base64` instead.

Comment: i have tried this public List<HubxTestApprovedForPatientModels> Base64 { get; set; } still getting nulll

Comment: `public List<object> Base64`

Comment: public List<object> Base64 which object i have to use here

Comment: can't we use `object` here directly?

Comment: i have shared a model please check

Comment: when I changed model to `public object Base64`, then base64 become `base64:["a", "b"]`, I can still receive the data. And since you mentioned `The only data which i'm receiving null is base64 data`, could you pls try to use `public object Base64` instead? because array/string/int they all object. I think you can use `object` and check what kind of data you received. You can see the last screenshot, using `object` will show you the data type